# Alignment into button(javafx)

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2

I have a button with image and text, but their alignment is incorrect, i need:
TEXT -> IMAGE, but i have IMAGE -> TEXT. I've tried to create `HBox` and add it on button, but button have no getChildren() method, only getChildrenUnmodifiable(), then i tried to use
`btn.setAlignment()` method, but it moves both objects, so it would be nice to hear some offers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you don't need hbox or something else. just add you image to your button and

```
    button.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
```